# Is it possible to setup the file watcher in LESS to have the output file with different name from the source?

Tags: intellij-idea, less, webstorm

I'm working with a `style.less` file and I'd like to know if it's possible to output a `theme.css` file when I compile. How can can configure the file watcher to achieve this?

**Here's my current configuration:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - just specify `theme.css` as a target file name:

[image]